# Fetch and execution cycle

Tags: memory, memory-management

Im trying to understand the instructions cycle of a cpu and how it executes instructions.

From my understanding, while a program is compiled into binary it is stored on the hard drive. When you run the program, the binary execution code is loaded into RAM and the binary resides in the .text area of the memory space for a process. However, im confused as to why the return address needs to stored on the stack. If we are executing 10 instructions, say the 3rd instruction is a function call, the kernal begins allocating memory for the function and also for the return address. Ive have read that the return address is the next instruction from the EIP register. Here, would the return address be the 4th instruction located in memory so that when the stack for the function is torn down again, we instructions will continue executing from the 4th? When the function executes, do the instructions jump from 3rd to 8th for example?

This is the source if it helps:
[https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/%7Echang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml)

> Next, main pushes the arguments for foo one at a time, last argument
> first onto the stack. For example, if the function call is:
>
> ```
>  a = foo(12, 15, 18) ; The assembly language instructions might be:
>     push    dword 18 
>     push    dword 15
>     push    dword 12 Finally, main can issue the subroutine call instruction:
>     call    foo
> ```
>
> When the call instruction is executed, the contents of the EIP register is pushed onto the stack. Since the EIP
> register is pointing to the next instruction in main, the effect is
> that the return address is now at the top of the stack. After the call
> instruction, the next execution cycle begins at the label named foo.
> Figure 2 shows the contents of the stack after the call instruction.
> The red line in Figure 2 and in subsequent figures indicates the top
> of the stack prior to the instructions that initiated the function
> call process. We will see that after the entire function call has
> finished, the top of the stack will be restored to this position

Any help is appreciated, thankyou

Comment: "While a program is compiled into binary, it is stored on the hard drive." - This is an ambiguous statement. The actual compilation is just a set of instructions done by the CPU, so anything the CPU needs to read (all of the source code) for compilation has to be brought up through the memory hierarchy, so some or all the source code is resident in RAM and caches during compilation, in addition to being backed completely in the hard drive.

Comment: "the binary resides in the .text area of the memory space for a process" - The binary for Linux refers to ELF files. These files contain [other sections](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) than `.text`. It's just that `.text` contains the executable code for the program. So the binary includes the code (`.text`), but it's not accurate to say the binary is in `.text.`.

Comment: An easy way I think about why there is a need to store return addresses is thinking about recursive functions. If my program contains one recursive function that calls itself 100 times during execution, (assume the compiler doesn't convert my function to a loop), then would we want our binary ELF file to have all 100 function instructions repeated? No, we'd rather save space, list it once in the ELF file, then just keep track of current and return addresses in a separate location than the executable code itself. That's what the IP (instruction pointer) and return address on stack are for.

Comment: We always know where we are at a given instruction (IP) and we know where to go once we return (i.e., when we hit return, we pop off the current function variables off the stack and we're left with the return address at the top of the stack, so we know where to go). If all this is helpful, I'm happy to make this into an answer.

Comment: As an addendum, not only would storing all 100 calls in the ELF file be a waste of space, we don't necessarily know before running the program that it will just be 100 calls. So we need to have a way to keep track of where we are in the code and where we were no matter how many times we go into or out of instructions.

Comment: You've done a good job of writing information without answering the question. However, it was good because i didnt know about executable formats

Comment: Which part specifically didn't answer your question?